# In bootstrap 4 if hide and show with jquery the columns lost flex

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, hide, show

With bootstrap 3 i can hide a row with css and show it with jquery.
If i do this with bootstrap4 the columns into row lost flex.

Why this? There is a solution for this problem? 
I have many code write for bs3 !!

```css
 .nascosto{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onClick='$("#test").show()'>test</div>
    
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row nascosto" id="test">
    
    
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    content
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    content
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    content
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    content
    </div>
    
    </div>
    </div>
```

if click on "test" the column no more flex.

Only in bs4, in 3 always work

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from using `show()` to display the row. `show()` makes the element block, but you need it to be flex.

So instead you can try with `$("#test").css('display', 'flex')`

That should fix the problem.

It works in Bootstrap 3 because, as far as I remember, Bootstrap < 4 uses floats for the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage visibility using Jquery.

```js
$('#testHeader').on('click',function(){

  if(!$('#test').is(":visible"))
  {
    $("#test").show()
  }
  else
  {
    $("#test").hide()
  }

})
```

```css
.nascosto{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id="testHeader">test</div>
    
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row nascosto" id="test">
        
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    content
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    content
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    content
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    content
    </div>
    
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/t5wo74rd/

test

```
<div class="container">
<div class="nascosto" id="test">   

<div class="row">


<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
content
</div>

<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
content
</div>

<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
content
</div>

<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
content
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
 .nascosto{display:none}
```

Comment: Please explain how you answer solves the OP's problem?

Comment: I have just added a new div element and show this div when click. Please check my demo url and change screen size (preview area) in jsfiddle.